# Making two columns out of a single variable?

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I currently have a variable that returns X amount of forms back to the template and to try and save space on the page I want to try and split these up into two columns but I'm kinda stumped on how to do this because I just have X as a variable in my html generating forms so there is nothing to section off/tell to go into the second column. So how can I get these forms generated from one variable to separate out into 2 columns?

Comment: When you say the forms are in a variable, do you mean you have a list or tuple of forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle) template tag to float the forms left and right. Something like:

```
<style>
.column{
    width:50%;
}
</style>

{% for form in forms %}
<div class="column" style="float:{% cycle 'left' 'right' %}">
     {{ form }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome! This does pretty much exactly what I wanted! thanks!